# Large solution ClickOnce distribution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I have a larger solution that I desire to distribute via ClickOnce. It consists of one main shell executable that directly references only a small subsection of libraries and processes that constitute the solution.

The solution consists of a few other processes and several libraries (some [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++)). I need to be able to include all of these libraries and processes in one ClickOnce distribution for both local builds and [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) server builds.

I cannot reference every other library and process form the shell project. And I do not wish to push these files into a [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) to be treated as a prerequisite as it would defeat the purpose of using ClickOnce to distribute/update the product.

What is the correct method to incorporate all of our necessary files/projects into a single ClickOnce distribution?

Answer (score 1):

The IDE won't detect native DLLs as dependencies when publishing, but you can run the SDK tools directly to include them manually in your ClickOnce distribution. You can either use mage.exe in your post-build script or run MageUI.exe to have a wizard to guide you through the package generation.

Suggested reading:

- [Walkthrough: Manually Deploying a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx)
- [Understanding Dependencies of a Visual C++ Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235265.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to Visual Studio for this kind of situation. You could try using [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but it can be a little tricky to use. My company wrote an alternative called ClickOnceMore.

[ClickOnceMore](http://clickoncemore.net) is a ClickOnce build tool for when you don't want or can't use Visual Studio to do ClickOnce builds.

There is a specific page on the UI for including files (using rules to include anything from a single file to an entire directory trees) so you should be able to do exactly what you need with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done in a similar situation. I use TFS at work, so convert the terms to whatever you may use (or not use) for source control.

I have a main workspace that I use for all development of my application, I keep this workspace pristine.

I then created another workspace with a proper name (ex: solution-deploy) and in this workspace I do the following:

1. Get latest and merge everything from source-control into the deployment workspace
2. I build a Release build of my application
3. I r-click on the root (I put them in the root, because I need to access them from there, put them in whatever folder you want) project folder for my deployment project and select "Add -> Existing Item"
4. I browse in the file selector to the Release directory of the assemblies I want to add to my deployment package, select them, then I use the arrow next to the Add button and drop down to "Add As Link", do this for all of the assemblies you want to add and place them wherever you want them to be organized in your deployment
5. In the Solution Explorer, select the added assemblies and in the Properties window set the Build Action to "Content", this should be all you have to do, but others have had to also set the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always", I don't do that
6. Run a Release Build
7. Go to the Properties view for your deployment Project
8. Go to the Publish Tab and Click on the Application Files button
9. Your files should all be available and added to the Deployment
10. Set up your ClickOnce settings however you need them to be
11. Publish your ClickOnce package

Your published package should contain all of the assemblies you need now.

Keep your separate Deployment workspace set up this way and never check it in. Do your work in your development workspace. Whenever a new deployment is needed, open your solution in your Deployment workspace and get the latest code, build, then publish.